# Is there a way to completely hide closed questions?

Tags: support

I keep finding myself reading questions only to notice later that they are closed.  Is there a user-preference for hiding all [closed] questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to hide closed question (unless you write a custom Javascript). However, while searching, you can used the `closed:0` parameter to remove closed questions from search results.